# Recreating nohup.out

Tags: java, linux, shell, logging, nohup

I'm a new to a Linux, I've encountered an issue. What I've done: i have created the shell script which runs jar file that inside have the System.out.println - prints. Then I ran the sh using: "nohup myScript.sh". It started to produce nohup.out file that appends my output from jar file. Then after hours I found that file very large and just ran a command: "rm nohup.out".

Is there a way to tell nohup to continue to write the output? Without killing currently running process and re-run "nohup myScript.sh"? Because what jar does, it migrating the data between two different environments. So I won't to kill it and start all process again.

Please, provide me some useful information or if u had been in the same issue, how did u solve it?

Cheers

Comment: The command you ran did not free any disk space, it just removed the directory entry for `nohup.out`.  nohup is still writing to the open file handle and will not free it until the process ends.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but is there any chance to continue read the nohup.out in tail -100f?

Comment: You can access the data of an open but anonymous file via /proc/pid/fd/, where pid is the nohup process id.